# python code error in mapping file values to list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists structured somehow like this:

```
A= [[1,27],[2,27],[3,27],[4,28],[5,29]]
B= [[6,30],[7,31],[8,31]]
```

and i have a file that has numbers:

```
1     5
2     3
3     1
4     2
5     5
6....
```

i want a code that reads this file and maps it to the list. e.g if the file has 1, it should read A list and output 27, if it has 6, it should read B and print 30, such that I get

```
27 29
27 27
27 27
28 27
29 29
30 31
```

The problem is, that my code gives index error, i read the file line by line and have an if condition that checks if the number i read from the file is less than the maximum number in list A, if so, it outputs the second character of that list and otherwise move on. The problem is, that instead of moving on to list B, my program still reads A and gives index error.

```
with open(filename) as myfile:
  for line in myfile.readlines():
     parts=line.split()
      if parts[0]< maxnumforA:
        print A[int(parts[0])-1]
      else:
        print B[int(parts[0]-1)
```

Comment: How do you get `maxnumforA` ?

Comment: `parts[0]` is a string, how are you comparing it to `maxnumforA` (or rather, what is `maxnumforA`?)?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary rather than a list? Is there a reason why you've split the list across two variables?

Comment: As an aside, you do not need to call ```file.readlines()``` to iterate over lines in a file.  [You can just write](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) ```for line in file:```

Comment: maxnumforA is 29, i define it earlier in my code. Yes, I need to split the data in two halves because it is required later. For use later in the code, I cannot combine the two lists

Comment: how are the numbers in the file? One in each line? Also, what if number is smaller than 29 but not contained in A? I do not see anything above 5 so that should be the `maxnumforA`

Comment: When asking a question about code that throws an exception you should always post the complete Traceback.   You als need to include enough information for us to reproduce your problem.  As mentioned by @UnholySheep we didn't know what ```maxnumforA``` is.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: sorry about that wwii. The code is pretty huge and has a bunch of variables. I did not want to confuse you all by writing the actual whole problem because it has a bunch of other things. I simplified and just wrote my problem. But yeah you are totally right. It is difficult to help without having the actual thing, I ll be careful next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn that lists into dictionaries. For example:

```
_A = dict(A)
_B = dict(B)

with open(filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        parts = line.split()
        for part in parts:
            part = int(part)
            if part in _A:
                print _A[part]
            elif part in _B:
                print _B[part]
```

If the action that will take place does not need to know if it comes from A or B, both can be turned into a single dictionary:

```
d = dict(A + B)  # Creating the dictionary

with open(filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        parts = line.split()
        for part in parts:
            part = int(part)
            if part in d:
                print d[part]
```

Creating the dictionary can be acomplished in many different ways, I will list some of them:

- `d = dict(A + B)`: First joins both lists into a single list (without modifying `A` or `B`) and then turns the result into a dictionary. It's the most clear way to do it.
- `d = {**dict(A), **dict(B)}`: Turns both lists into two separates dictionaries (without mmodifying `A` or `B`), unpacks them and pack both of them into a single dictionary. Slighlty (and I mean really slightly) faster than the previous method and less clear. Proposed by @Nf4r
- `d = dict(A)` & `d.update(B)`: Turns the first list into a dictionary and updates that dictionary with the content of the second list. Fastest method, 1 line of code per list instead of 1 line for any list and no temporary objects generation so more efficient memory-wise.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Simple and clear. solved the problem

Comment: @LilySharpton if you are going to do the same if it is located in A or B you could swap the code a bit to use a single dict as I suggested in a comment below, editing my answer to include this too

Comment: @Adirio check my answer to your statement below, because you are wrong.

Comment: @Nf4r I checked and your benchmark is not right, you are comparing your answer with an invented one. My answer is as fast as yours and is way more clear. If speed is a must dict updating is the fastest way to do it. Will include all the proposed solutions on the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone stated before, dict would be much better. I don't know if the left-sided values in each lists are unique, but if yes, you could just go for:

```
d = {**dict(A), **dict(B)} # available in Python 3.x
with open(filename) as file: 
    for line in file.readlines():
        for num in line.split():
            if int(num) in d:
                print(d[int(num)])
```

Comment: Creating two dictionaries to unpack them to create a third one is a bad solution, you could have gone for `d = dict(A+B)`

Comment: Actualy the way I've done is is much faster than your way. By saing `d = dict(A + B)` you are creating extra list and then iterating over it. I've done a simple session, which you can check on: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cedc9ce814edd1b8ec71395ceaf55e05

Comment: That gist is not right: you are comparing your solution `d = {**dict(A), **dict(B)}` with an invented solution `d = {**dict(A + B)}` that is actually unpacking and packing the dictionary for no benefit. My answer (`d = dict(A+B)`) takes more or less the same time yours does, you can check. If you want to be fast use dict updating: `d = dict(A); d.update(B)`. The gist comparing your solution with both of the can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Adirio/4e566b7570ccdb044a5c25eec9fd3ccd